# Как использовать переменную CSS в URL-адресе ('data: image / svg + xml')

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg, css-variables

Я использую следующее, чтобы получить пунктирную границу вокруг div:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg stroke="black" width="100%25" height="100%25" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"%3e%3crect width="100%25" height="100%25" fill="none" rx="16px" ry="16px" stroke-width="6" stroke-dasharray="5%25%2c 2%25" stroke-dashoffset="4" stroke-linecap="butt"/%3e%3c/svg%3e');
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Можно ли заменить черный цвет обводки на переменную CSS? К сожалению, не работает следующее:

```
div {
  --color: black;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg stroke="var(--color)" width="100%25" height="100%25" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"%3e%3crect width="100%25" height="100%25" fill="none" rx="16px" ry="16px" stroke-width="6" stroke-dasharray="5%25%2c 2%25" stroke-dashoffset="4" stroke-linecap="butt"/%3e%3c/svg%3e');
}
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Use CSS variable in url('data:image/svg+xml')](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67025375/7394871) от участника  [@Tonald Drump](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7437878/tonald-drump).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/67025375/7394871

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте иначе, используя маску:

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  -webkit-mask: url('data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg stroke="black" width="100%25" height="100%25" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"%3e%3crect width="100%25" height="100%25" fill="none" rx="16px" ry="16px" stroke-width="6" stroke-dasharray="5%25%2c 2%25" stroke-dashoffset="4" stroke-linecap="butt"/%3e%3c/svg%3e');
  background:var(--c,red);
  border-radius: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" style="--c:green"></div>
<div class="box" style="--c:blue"></div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67027543/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>